# How to set SetSqlGenerator and CodeGenerator in MySql Connector 6.9.6?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I updated my MySql connector/net to 6.9.6 (from 6.9.5) and EF to 6.1.3 (from 6.1.2) which broke migrations :(

I used to have this, which would make migrations work on MySql.

```
public Configuration()
{
    // fails with cannot assign MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator toSystem.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.MigrationSqlGenerator
    SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());

    // fails with cannot assign MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator to System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationCodeGenerator
    CodeGenerator = new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
}
```

But now that doesn't work. And when I remove it the generated migrations are prefixed with `dbo` which doesn't work.

I tried setting the *new* config in the web.config

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

also tried setting the *new* attribute on the context.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyContext : DbContext
```

But to no avail.

How do I make migrations work again with this new connector?

Comment: I have a similar issue, with `System.Data.SQLite` provider. I upgraded EF from 6.1.x to 6.2.x and now it doesn't work. I've set a breakpoint in my Generator class and it doesn't hit there.